# Can't find mysql data in install directory

Tags: mysql, windows-7-x64

I was looking for my mysql data on my harddrive, so i went to the install directory (C:\ProgrammData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data) but there are only a few of the databases displayed I actually use. Hidden folders are enabled so far...
Is there any other directory I should check?
I'm running Windows 7 x64...

Comment: Check your MySQL config files as you may have told it to use a different data directory.

Comment: Try at http://superuser.com/

Comment: You mean the my-default.ini? I already looked in it, the parts where the paths have to be is empty... (just 3 dots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open your my.ini and search for "datadir" example :

```
datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/Data/"
```

May be your config have somewhere else to look..

In case if you dont know where your my.ini was loaded, you can

```
1. windows+run
2. type services.msc enter
3. search for mysql services..
4. right click -> properties
5. see "Path to executable" (should be there for your my.ini)
```

Comment: I can't find my `my.ini`. it isn't located in my install directory, where do i have to look for??

Comment: @drrtyrokka:  look at `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini`

Comment: There it says the path you say `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini`. But I cannot see any such file in this directory... how can this be?? I activated hidden folders...but there is nothing... going mad with this...

Comment: OOOOOh, now I got it :D Not `Program Files`, it is in `Program Data`. Sucha fail :P That appears if you use Windows in german and you don't actually know the difference...